# efficient way of accessing values in a tuple (python)

Tags: python, class, tuples

i have a function that returns a tuple of

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

i also have a class that requires 10 total args (including self)

i want the tuple to be able to populate the args in the class, but if i just put

```
y = Class(x)
```

it returns the error

```
> TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 10 arguments (2 given)
```

i know it would be possible to just use

```
y = Class(x[0], x[1], ... x[8])
```

but that seems awfully long winded. is there some better method of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the asterisk to [unpack argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
Class(*x)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to [unpack](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) it:

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j):
...     return a
... 
>>> x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
>>> foo(*x)
1
```

Comment: I see this get called the 'splat' operator a lot. Useful thing.